# How to get all mime types Google Drive Api IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, mime-types, google-drive-api

I am trying to integrate Google Drive Api for IOS. I am testing their example [program here](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/objectivec)

a.k.a DrEdit when they upload or download a file they use mimetype such as when they upload a file

`[GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:fileContent MIMEType:@"text/plain"];`

when api downloads the same file it uses

`GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
  query.q = @"mimeType = 'text/plain'";`

JSON values for a file

```
{
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "id": string,
  "etag": etag,
  "selfLink": string,
  "title": "file_name",
  "mimeType": "mime/type",
  "description": "Stuff about the file"
  ...
  "downloadUrl": string,
  ...
}
```

Now I wonder how can I download all the files in users folder that has different file extensions such as pdf,doc etc...

How can I display/list all the documents in users google drive account?

Comment: Check Google Drive's [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes#requesting_full_drive_scope_for_an_app) you can query all files (read only) maybe from there you could choose files to download.

Answer (score 6):

Two things:

1) The empty query seems to return all files:

```
query.q = @"";
```

2) Make sure you request access to all files in the auth (initWithScope:**kGTLAuthScopeDrive**).  The DrEdit example defaults to only accessing files created by the app.

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController = 
  [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive    // Auth to all files and docs
                                             clientID:kClientId
                                         clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                     keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                             delegate:self
                                     finishedSelector:finishedSelector];
```

Answer (score 0):

[Mime types](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads)

I have found this mime types which are supported by google drive. U can use them in download or upload.